# Unistalling the package... > Fail

Tags: tizen

I'm a very newbie in Tizen projects. 
I'm trying to run my application in a Samsung Smart TV (UE40KU6000) and I'm getting this error:

```
`Uninstalling the package... > Fail
 Unexpected error occurred at the below step.
 Uninstalling the package...
Tizen Web Application uninstall failed. Please try again later.`
```

But the error persist, so what can I do? Can you help me?

Here the console log: 
`

```
[Initializing the launch environment...]
    RDS: On
    Target information: UE40KU6000
    Application information: Id(Dtc1PodNg3.TestSample), Package Name(Dtc1PodNg3), Project Name(TizenTvSample)
[Transferring the package...]
    Transferred the package: wgt stream -> /opt/usr/apps/tmp/TizenTvSample.wgt
[Uninstalling the package...]
uninstall Dtc1PodNg3.TestSample
app_id[Dtc1PodNg3.TestSample] uninstall start
app_id[Dtc1PodNg3.TestSample] uninstall failed[132]
spend time for wascmd is [52]ms
cmd_ret:0
Unexpected stop progress...
(31.353 sec)
```

`

Answer (score 2):

Try to uninstall the package manually. Go to the Apps on your TV and uninstall the app. That could help.

Comment: There's nothing to uninstall from there, it doesn't show up.